# i want to calculate sum(sigma) of given x, y while 1<=i<=10 like that : (x+y)^(i^2)-i+1 without the pow() function

Tags: loops, while-loop, sum, exp

I want to build a function to compute  `(x+y)` in powers of `(i*i)-i+1` for `i` from 1 to 10. I can't find the missmatch in my code... For `x= 0.25` and `y = 0.5` the result should be 1.331  but my result is 0.8

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <math.h>
    
      double double_bitxy ( double x , double y )
      {
           double base = (x + y);
           int i = 10 ;
           double result = 0 , temp = 0 ;
           temp = base ;
    
           for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)    
           {
               int exp = ((i * i) - i + 1) ;
               while (exp!= 0)
               {
                   temp = temp * base ;
                   --exp ;
               }
               result += temp ;
           }
           return result ;
      }
      
      int main()
      {
           double  x , y ;
           printf("enter x\n") ;
           scanf("%lf", &x) ;
           printf("enter y\n") ;
           scanf("%lf", &y) ;
       
           double sum = double_bitxy(x , y);
    
           printf("%lf", sum);
    
           return 0;
      }
```

Comment: i am not getting the right result, i thimk the value of the exp for everi i-- run may br wrong ?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, including your attempts to resolve the problem